# No such Module Error

Tags: swift

I am working on a chat app using Swift, and cocoa pods and I keep getting this issue. It says no such module JSQMessagesViewController, and the pod file is set up just like the tutorial wants me to do it. If you need me to show you the pod file just let me know and I will put it in there.

Thanks Luc

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController
import syncano_ios

let syncanoChannelName = "messages"

class ViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

let syncano = Syncano.sharedInstanceWithApiKey("7f5312e4808d69df6bd258b444b13d5d5956c15d", instanceName: "small-waterfall-9948")
let channel = SCChannel(name: syncanoChannelName)

let incomingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 180/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1.0))
let outgoingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor())
var messages = [JSQMessage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.setup()
    self.downloadNewestMessagesFromSyncano()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func reloadMessagesView() {
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
}

//MARK - Setup
extension ViewController {
func addDemoMessages() {
    for i in 1...10 {
        let sender = (i%2 == 0) ? "Server" : self.senderId
        let messageContent = "Message nr. \(i)"
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: sender, displayName: sender, text: messageContent)
        self.messages += [message]
    }
    self.reloadMessagesView()
}

func setup() {
    self.senderId = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString
    self.senderDisplayName = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString
    self.channel.delegate = self
    self.channel.subscribeToChannel()
}
}

//MARK - Data Source
extension ViewController {

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.messages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    let data = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    return data
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didDeleteMessageAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    self.messages.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let data = messages[indexPath.row]
    switch(data.senderId) {
    case self.senderId:
        return self.outgoingBubble
    default:
        return self.incomingBubble
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
}
}

//MARK - Toolbar
extension ViewController {
override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {
    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, text: text)
    self.messages += [message]
    self.sendMessageToSyncano(message)
    self.finishSendingMessage()
}

override func didPressAccessoryButton(sender: UIButton!) {

}
}

//MARK - Syncano
extension ViewController {

func sendMessageToSyncano(message: JSQMessage) {
    let messageToSend = Message()
    messageToSend.text = message.text
    messageToSend.senderId = self.senderId
    messageToSend.channel = syncanoChannelName
    messageToSend.other_permissions = .Full
    messageToSend.saveWithCompletionBlock { error in
        if (error != nil) {
            //Super cool error handling
        }
    }
}

func downloadNewestMessagesFromSyncano() {
    Message.please().giveMeDataObjectsWithCompletion { objects, error in
        if let messages = objects as? [Message]! {
            self.messages = self.jsqMessagesFromSyncanoMessages(messages)
            self.finishReceivingMessage()
        }
    }
}

func jsqMessageFromSyncanoMessage(message: Message) -> JSQMessage {
    let jsqMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: message.senderId, senderDisplayName: message.senderId, date: message.created_at, text: message.text)
    return jsqMessage
}

func jsqMessagesFromSyncanoMessages(messages: [Message]) -> [JSQMessage] {
    var jsqMessages : [JSQMessage] = []
    for message in messages {
        jsqMessages.append(self.jsqMessageFromSyncanoMessage(message))
    }
    return jsqMessages
}
}

//MARK - Channels
extension ViewController : SCChannelDelegate {

func addMessageFromNotification(notification: SCChannelNotificationMessage) {
    let message = Message(fromDictionary: notification.payload)
    if message.senderId == self.senderId {
        //we don't need to add messages from ourselves
        return
    }
    self.messages.append(self.jsqMessageFromSyncanoMessage(message))
    self.finishReceivingMessage()
}

func updateMessageFromNotification(notification: SCChannelNotificationMessage) {

}

func deleteMessageFromNotification(notification: SCChannelNotificationMessage) {

}

func chanellDidReceivedNotificationMessage(notificationMessage: SCChannelNotificationMessage!) {
    switch(notificationMessage.action) {
    case .Create:
        self.addMessageFromNotification(notificationMessage)
    case .Delete:
        self.deleteMessageFromNotification(notificationMessage)
    case .Update:
        self.updateMessageFromNotification(notificationMessage)
    default:
        break
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you included  `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile?

Answer (score 11):

Do the following things and you can import any swift file from "Pods"

> 1) Clean your project
>
> 2) Make sure that all your "Pods" > "Build Settings" > "Build Active
>   Architecture Only" is set to "NO".
>
> 3) Don't run, just build your project.
>
> 4) Now, import any file from "Pods" to any swift file
>
> E.g.: import JSQMessagesViewController
>
> 5) Again, build project and it will work as expected. Finally, you can
>   access it properties

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did the first three now how do I import a file from "Pods" to any swift file and how do I import the JSQMessagesViewController.

Comment: @LucMollard Just write the import statement in any `UIViewController` you need to use `JSQMessagesViewController`

Comment: Yes I have completed that. @Sohil R. Memon

Comment: Ya after I build it again it says build failed and the error is still there. Anything Else?

Comment: No it is the same error. What I meant by anything else was if there is any other problem resolutions.

Comment: @LucMollard It should work. This is the only way I get through the error.

Comment: My issue got resolved according to the step 2). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Once you installed your Pods, close xCode. Then open it back using the following command line:

> $ open App.xcworkspace

I had the same issue than you and it worked for me. Took this info from https://cocoapods.org/.