# No Such Module Eureka found in XCode 7

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Xcode 7 project, where in i Installed the `cocoa pods` using the pod install. Installation success for pods. Opened the Xcode project, tried building it, project giving me an error saying "No such module Eureka". I use `Cocoapods` for some of the more common Swift frameworks `(e.g. Eureka, SwiftyJSON, JLToast etc.)`
When I see the Frameworks folder, I can see all the frameworks are missing.

Searched many links, unfortunately none of the suggestions worked for me.

Can I get some help on this please ? I am not getting why the frameworks are missing even after installing the pods.

Comment: Clean Xcode > Cmd+Shift+K

Comment: Pls check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440296/no-such-module-error/36440339#36440339

Answer (score 1):

You have to check few things first

1. Add libraries to Embedded Binaries in General Tab in Xcode.
2. Double check your libraries are written in below Swift 3+.

Hope it helps.